# files wrote by write() couldn't open in windows

Tags: python, web.py

The code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8 -*-

import web

urls=('/','index')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        web.header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8")
        return """<html><head></head><body>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="file" name="mainTable" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </body></html>"""
    def POST(self):
        i=web.input(mainTable={})
        fout=open(".\\tables\\main.xls",'w')
        fout.write(i.mainTable.file.read())
        fout.close()
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=web.application(urls,globals())
    app.run()
```

I put this on a linux server, and it works, an excel file was uploaded successfully(the path format must be changed, of course),and I can download it and open it with excel.

But when I put this on a Windows server, files were uploaded but I can't open it. The excel said the file is damaged. So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters
>   to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.
>   Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode
>   value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.
>   (Appending `'b'` is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and
>   text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)

```
fout=open(".\\tables\\main.xls", 'wb')
```